# Parent id is not saved in child table Spring JPA2 @OneToMany relation

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-cloud-feign

I have json like as shown below which comes from a third party service which I gets it through open feign client. I am trying to save these details into my MySQL database using Spring JPA2.

```
[
  {
    "request_id": 111,
    "name": "ABC",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 21,
        "group": "grp_A"
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "group": "grp_B"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "request_id": 222,
    "name": "ABC",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 23,
        "group": "grp_C"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "request_id": 333,
    "name": "ABC",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 24,
        "group": "grp_A"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "request_id": 444,
    "name": "ABC",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 25,
        "group": "grp_C"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "request_id": 555,
    "name": "ABC",
    "groups": []
  }
]
```

I have wrote the mappings for the above json like as shown blow

**Requests.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "requests")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Requests {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "request_id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Groups> groups = Sets.newHashSet();

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Groups.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Groups{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "group")
    private String group;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "request_id")
    private Requests requests;

    // getters and setters
}
```

now within my service class I have done like as shown below

```
List<Requests> allRequests = requestFeignClient.getRequests();
requestRepository.saveAll(allRequests);
```

all details are saved into the database except the **request_id** like as shown below. My Expected group table is also shown below

[image]

Can anyone please tell me why the **request_id** is not getting saved.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

With this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "requests", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: I tried that but I am getting this exception ```Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.test.model.Groups.request_id in com.test.model.Requests.groups```

Comment: Try "requests" instead of "request_id"

Comment: The parent reference also needs to be set on all the children. No way you will get that from just deserialising that json with Jackson. I would either introduce DTOs or you need to iterate the children and set the parent in each before saving.